# How to convert string data into date format in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdate, xcode4.4

In my app, i am taking date and time in to string  **" 2013-06-11 10:15:00 +0000 "** like this, but how can i convert this string into date format. I tried like below code but i am getting error in converting.

```
NSString *string=@"03-05-2014";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
```

Would you please help me in this problem?

Comment: what you are getting in dateFromString ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
NSDateFormatter* f = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

NSDate *dateFromString = [f dateFromString:string];

You have to set the same date format in which the (string or date)contains, otherwise the date is returned by `NSDateFormatter` will be nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use NSCalender Like this.....

**NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];**

Refer This Link : [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urDateString=@"2013-06-11 10:15:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *strDate = [urDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+0000" withString:@""];
NSDate *dateString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-DD-yyyy"];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",formattedDateString);
```

Comment: i am getting this error whenever running your code.   2013-06-11 17:02:08.059 Timersutesh[3071:c07] gettime is 2013-06-11 11:31:58 +0000
2013-06-11 17:02:12.469 Timersutesh[3071:c07] -[__NSDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d61160
2013-06-11 17:02:12.470 Timersutesh[3071:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d61160'

Comment: see if your urDateString is same as mine?? what are u passing to stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString is string only??